# How to convert a constructor function to a class declaration in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am constantly getting a suggestion from VSCode IntelliSense that this constructor function may be Converted into class declaration.

I searched on stackOverflow about it, but what I am getting is the way to turn this suggestion off.

**I want to know how Can I convert a Constructor function to a class declaration?**

***just for reference*** : It is the code where I am getting this suggestion.

```
UserSchema.pre('save',function async () {
    if(user.isModified('password')) {
        this.password = await hash(this.password,8)
    }
})
```

***ScreenShot***
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: can you post the screenshot of the error message?

Comment: Uploaded. Sample Codes are not the things to worry about.I just forgot removing them from ScreenShot.

Comment: That's a bug in your linter - there is no constructor function in that line. Which linter are you using, which rule does cause this warning? Report an issue.

Comment: Ok I will report it, but I want to know in general that how this can be done.

Comment: Unrelated, but `async` is a terrible name for a function. Name it after what it does.

Comment: For class declaration, read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @DaveNewton Oh, wow, I didn't even notice it's `function async` not `async function`. The `await` keyword in the body should actually cause a syntax error then. Maybe this is what also confused the parser enough to make the linter complain.

Comment: @AKS Please study the rule documentation for that, or post a concrete example where you actually have a constructor function.